# CSS opacity background color and text not working

Tags: css, opacity

I'm making an app for FireFox OS and I want to make button background opacity 0.5 and the text opacity 1 but it doesn't work. Check the css:

```
.button{
    height:40px;
    width:180px;
    border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    border: 1px solid #FF9924;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#FF9924;
    padding-top:5px;
    opacity:0.5;
}


h1{
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: firstone;
    opacity:1.0;
}
```

on page:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="button"><h1>Start the fight</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is the difference between [opacity and alpha](http://jsfiddle.net/LgYDE/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should read about [rgba](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba%28%29)

This is the syntax:

```
 .button {
      background-color: rgba(255, 153, 36, 0.5)
 }
```

Here's a [Hex-to-RGB Color Converter](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `rgba()` to set the `background-color` with desired `opacity` It won't change the text's opacity.

Read more about rgba at [CSS3.INFO](http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/)

```
.button {
   //...
   background-color: rgba(255, 153, 36, 0.5); 
   //...
}
```

See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/p9pJy/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't give `opacity` only to the background without affecting the rest...
Instead, try with `alpha` in `background-color`.

Ex.

```
.button{
  background-color: #FF9924; // for browser that don't accept alpha in color
  background-color: rgba(255, 153, 36, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems impossible indeed. You can try making a .buttonwrapper instead of .button. Inside .buttonwrapper you place two absolute positioned layers, one with the actual button with an opacity of 0.5, and one above it with the text at opacity of 1, without background.

```
<div class="buttonwrapper">
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button_text"><h1>Text</h1></div>
</div>
```